# Why do I keep getting undefined

Tags: javascript, html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
   
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="name">bbb</h1>


</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("name").innerHTML;

alert(text)
```

The output of the alert function is undefined
not sure where iam going wrong here

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Comment: @Phix, no it returns an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: Fair point, in any case it's not a single item.

Comment: @Rocky `HTMLCollection` does not have an `innerHTML` property, hence it is `undefined`. This is the typical mistake people make that have a jQuery background instead of learning JS first.